# why is the sys.path not the same in my python when run under tmux?

Tags: python, tmux

I have just installed `tmux` in order to run a long running python task with ssh.
However, it seems that the python from the `tmux` although has the same path and the same envvars defined as the one that is normally run outside tmux, has a very different `sys.path` which is much shorter.

Why is this and how can I make the python in tmux see the same sys.path as the python outside?